# Setting the runtime to netcore 3.1 LTS has broken our netcore 3.1app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

**See update 1 below:**

This is a Windows WebApp on Azure AppService on a premium app service plan (it is a webapi written on netcore 3.1 C# project)

After setting up a new webapp with netcore 3.1 using **az webapp create --runtime DOTNETCORE|3.1 (other params...)** and webdeploy the app, at this point the app works.

When I look at the portal appService Configuration / General / Runtime, the runtime is blank  If I set the runtime to .net / netcore 3.1 LTS through the UI, the app breaks (cannot start the W3 worker, events 2294 2276 are raised on startup).

Having spent a few hours thinking it was our app, I changed the runtime to net 5.0 and it started working.

Under the hood, the netFrameworkVersion property is being set like this:

- on deployment when we have set runtime to netcore 3.1:  4.0
- When selecting 3.1 LTS through the UI: 3.0
- When setting 5.0 Early Access through the UI : 5.0
- there is no property that seems to carry the DOTNETCORE|3.1 runtime value.

So to fix it rather than deleting and recreating the app service, I am trying to reset the runtime in CLI.

I can't find an **az webapp** CLI command to set the runtime like you can on **az webapp create**.  The only option I can find for update is **az webapp config** is to set the --net-frameworkversion to 4.0 which sets the runtime in the UI to ASPNET 4.5 which is not the same as when you use --runtime DOTNETCORE|3.1 in the **az webapp create** command.

Looking for 2 things:

- confirmation something is messed up in the Azure portal with the runtime setting.
- a work around to reset the runtime to netcore 3.1 LTS outside of the portal (az CLI, az powershell?)

**Update 1:**
I tried deploying an new premium app service plan in North Europe, a new app service, Netcore 3.1 on Windows.  No App Insights, networking, etc.  Deployed the Visual Studio starter webapi app (weather forecast).  Run it - it works.  Change the runtime from blank to net/netcore3.1 in the portal, fails as above.  Not one line of my own config or code in this scenario.

Feels to me like the portal may be messing up the app service config.

Also tried publishing from VS again with self contained 3.1 and it is no different.

Comment: Adding the extension did not help.  The problem is I can crash the app service and it recycles every 1 second just by changing that runtime setting in the config page from blank to netcore 3.1 LTS even though this is a netcore 3.1 c# webapp.  I am going to try with a vanilla webapp just in case there is a breaking change is startup on 3.1.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was a bug in Azure.  Now the portal Configuration/GeneralSettings lists netcore 3.1 as was set by the CLI create command.

The label changed too (3.1/2.1 used to be seperate entries).

I could not find any acknowledgement from MSFT.

[image]